# Perl script to find a word and remove all char/word on the first search

Tags: perl, scripting

Here is my input

```
/prj/mct/2.5/src/mode/session.v
/prj/act/data/1.6/src/log.v
```

Here I'm trying to find a numeric value from above path and I want to remove all data/path after finding the numeric value.

Expected output

```
/prj/mct/2.5/.
/prj/act/data/1.6/.
```

Can you please let me know how I should write a perl script for the same?

Answer (score 1):

The following one-liner gives the expected output:

```
perl -pe 's{([^0-9]+[0-9.]+/).*}{$1.}' input.txt
```

- `-p` reads the input line by line, printing each line after processing;
- `s{}{}` is the substitution, we're not using `s///` because we want to match a slash and we don't like backslashed slashes as they're hard to read;
- `[0-9]` matches a digit, `^` negates it, i.e. `[^0-9]` matches anything but a digit;
- `+` matches one or more occurrences of the preceding construct, e.g. `[^0-9]+` matches one or more non-digits;
- `[0-9.]+` matches digits and dots, i.e. a version;
- the `(...)` parentheses create a capture group, here we capture the whole beginning of each line up to the slash after the version;
- we replace the whole line with just the captured part and add a dot.

Comment: Isn't `[^0-9]` irrelevant there? It should be matching `/` with these inputs. `[0-9.]` may also match just periods e.g. `..`.

Comment: It works for the sample input. I'm not sure how wild the real lines can get, the regex might need some tweaking.

Comment: can you help me to full fill the code
my $path="/prj/mct/2.5/src/mode/session.v";
my $str;
$str=s{([^0-9]+[0-9.]+/).*}{$1.} $path ;
print $str ;

will it work?
how do we use "pe"  in this case?

Comment: `my $str = $path =~ s{([^0-9]+[0-9.]+/).*}{$1.}r;` or `(my $str = $path) =~ s{([^0-9]+[0-9.]+/).*}{$1.};` in older Perls.

Answer (score 1):

At its simplest, we can just match a numbers `\d+` with a period `\.` in the middle, enclosed by slashes, keep that part `\K` and discard the rest `.*`:

```
perl -pe 's#/\d+\.\d+/\K.*#.#' path.txt
```

This will match your current test cases, but does require periods. If you have a single digit, we can make that part optional:

```
perl -pe 's#/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/\K.*#.#' path.txt
```

`(?: ... )?` a non capturing parenthesis `(?:` with a `?` quantifier (match 0 or 1 times).

Using a character class is also an option, such as `[\d.]`, but bear in mind that this can also match only periods, e.g. `/../`.

```
perl -pe 's#/[\d.]+/\K.*#.#' path.txt
```